# EF6 migrations merged in script

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've got an Entity Framework 6 migration which adds a column to a table and runs some SQL to populate the new column with the correct data. The migration is as follows:

```
AddColumn("SiteBranches", "SiteId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0));

Sql(@"WITH WithSiteId AS
            (
                --get the relevant data
            )
            UPDATE SiteSurvey.SiteBranches
            SET SiteId = x.SiteId
            FROM (
                --use WithSiteId
            ) x
            WHERE SiteBranches.SiteBranchId = x.SiteBranchId;");
```

If I run the migration using "Update-Database", it works fine, and both commands are executed separately. However, if I use "Update-Database -script" it generates the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE [SiteBranches] ADD [SiteId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
WITH WithSiteId AS
(
   --etc etc.
)
```

Running this script treats this as a single command, not two separate commands. I can easily solve this by putting a semi-colon after the `ALTER TABLE` command, but my concern is that the script will be generated by someone else in the future for deployment to a different environment, and they wouldn't know to do that.

Is there a way to write the migration which keeps these commands separate? I could put the semi-colon in the migration manually by replacing `AddColumn(...);` with `Sql("ALTER TABLE ... ;");` but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put `;` at the start of SQL like this

```
Sql(@";WITH WithSiteId AS
            (
                --get the relevant data
            )
            UPDATE SiteSurvey.SiteBranches
            SET SiteId = x.SiteId
            FROM (
                --use WithSiteId
            ) x
            WHERE SiteBranches.SiteBranchId = x.SiteBranchId;");
```

It's because `WITH` and Common Table Expression requires the previous statement  to be terminated using a `;`.

If you were adding 2 columns using `AddColumn` like in the example below, the generated script will not cause an error because `;` is optional.

```
AddColumn("SiteBranches", "SiteId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0))
AddColumn("SiteBranches", "SiteCode", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0))
```

Interesting article on `;` in SQL Server by Aaron Bertrand on [sqlblog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)